# Landscape view issue with navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, xcode9, ios-autolayout

Default Navigation bar height is 64.But after change it's orientation to landscape navigation bar height changed to 28.I want to set Fix navigation bar size in all orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add orientation observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

And add rotate method:

```
func rotated() {
    let height: CGFloat = 50 //whatever height you want to add to the existing height
    let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)
}
```

Comment: thanks for response.still not resolved.@maxwell navigation bar changes height 44 to 32 in landscape.Below that navigation bar I placed search bar with height  56.Still shows some space in between navigation bar and search bar in landscape